# Filtering on guid using OData (Microsoft Graph)

Tags: odata, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get a list of users with a certain license using the Microsoft Graph API. This can be tested using [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) .

This is a cropped example of what is returned for one user:

```js
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "id": "69615b5e-8b26-430c-ae89-4e626f5ba240",
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "assignedLicenses": [
        {
            "disabledPlans": [],
            "skuId": "f8a1db68-be16-40ed-86d5-cb42ce701560"
        },
        {
            "disabledPlans": [],
            "skuId": "6fd2c87f-b296-42f0-b197-1e91e994b900"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get a list of all users that have an assigned license with `skuId` of  "f8a1db68-be16-40ed-86d5-cb42ce701560"

This is what I've tried so far:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=AssignedLicenses/any(a:a/SkuId eq 'f8a1db68-be16-40ed-86d5-cb42ce701560')
```

Gives me the error:

> A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.Guid' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'Equal'.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=AssignedLicenses/any(a:a/SkuId eq f8a1db68-be16-40ed-86d5-cb42ce701560)
```

Gives me the error:

> ')' or ',' expected at position 42 in 'assignedLicenses/any(a:a/skuId eq f8a1db68-be16-40ed-86d5-cb42ce701560)'.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=AssignedLicenses/any(a:a/SkuId eq cast('f8a1db68-be16-40ed-86d5-cb42ce701560',Edm.Guid))
```

Give me the error:

> The child type 'Edm.Guid' in a cast was not an entity type. Casts can only be performed on entity types.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769844/microsoft-graph-api-filter-by-guid-value) suggests that my first try would work but it doesn't. Am I doing something wrong or is it just not possible to filter by license assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/assignedlicense), it seems this properties doesn't support filter since the other properties which support filter, the document will mentioned in the description filed like `accountEnabled` of `user` resource type( refer [this link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/user)).

You can submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis) if you want this property support filter.